# 'Cannot Increment end list iterator' Run-time error (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, list, visual-c++, unordered-map

Whenever I put in any amount of items in my list and attempt to convert them to an unordered map with an integer inside the list item as the key, I keep getting the error about the end-list iterator when I try to erase every element in the list. My code is below.

```
for (auto iter = tList.begin(); iter != tList.end(); iter++)
    {
        tMap[(*iter)->getID()] = move(*iter);
    }
//Specifically it's this section here with 2 iterators I'm having an issue with
    for (auto iter = tList.begin(); iter != tList.end(); iter++)
    {
        for (auto iter2 = iter; iter2 != tList.end(); iter2++)
        {
            tList.erase(iter, iter2);
            iter2++; 
            //Intentional so iter2 goes up by 2 each time while the first iter goes up by 1
        }
    }
    for (pair<int, Item *> e : tMap)
    {
        cout << e.first << " " << e.second << endl;
    }
    for (auto iter = t.begin(); iter != tMap.end(); iter++)
    {
        tMap.erase(iter);
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? You are not allowed to increment `iter2` if it is already pointing past-the-end (i.e. if `iter2 == tList.end()`), so if you increment it twice without checking for this condition, that's wrong. Erasing from `tlist` while iterating over it and iterating the same container in nested loops, that is also highly suspect.

Comment: After `tList.erase(iter, iter2)`, `iter` is not valid. Read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: By the way: If the two nested loops are supposed to be erasing all elements from `tList`, then you are completely off-track. `tList.clear()` removes all items from `tList` and usually (if the list is not going to be reused) this is done automatically by its destructor at scope exit. Same for `tMap` and the last loop. All of this assuming of course that `tList` is a `std::list` and `tMap` a `std::map`.

Comment: When you delete something inside a for loop of a list, iter ++ can give you an Undefined Bihavior.

Comment: `erase()` returns a new iterator to the next remaining element that is past the last element that was erased. So change `tList.erase(iter, iter2);` to `iter2 = tList.erase(iter, iter2);`, and check `iter2` for `end()` before calling `iter2++;`.

Comment: What is the type of `tList` ?